# Grep from a range of dates as filenames

Tags: regex, unix, ubuntu, grep, pattern-matching

I have multiple files which have raw CDRs in them. The files are named in the pattern `cdr.log-2013-06-08-0100`. There are multiple files like so:

```
cdr.log-2013-06-07-0000
cdr.log-2013-06-07-0100
.
.
cdr.log-2013-06-08-2200
cdr.log-2013-06-08-2300
```

I need to `grep` out a string from a range of files say between the date 6th june 2013 to 9th june 2013, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: try this http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/143155-searching-date-range-filenames.html

Answer (score 1):

To `grep` a string from `specific range` of file.

```
find . -regex ".*cdr\.log-2013-06-0[6-9]-.*" -exec grep 'your string' {} +
```

Comment: `zgrep "search text" /mnt/internal-app/logs/internal-app.log_2019-08-23*` works for me but `find . -regex "/mnt/internal-app/logs/internal-app.log_2019-08-23.*" -exec grep 'search text' {} +` does not work for me.